# problems "xtick","ytick", add legend... in Gaussian with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{conto}
\setcounter{conto}{\time}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\longto}{\longrightarrow}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Graph}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  mark=none,samples=50,smooth},
  axis x line=bottom, 
  axis y line=left, 
axis x line=middle,
xlabel={\(a \in  \mathbf{Set}(\{\mathbf{mis}_i(X)\}_{i=1}^6 )\)},
    ylabel={\(f_a^{\text{rel}}\)},
    axis y line=middle,
    xlabel={\(x\)},
    ylabel={\(\mathcal{G}_{u,p}(x)\)},
    every axis x label/.style={mark=none,smooth,
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=west,},
    every axis y label/.style={mark=none,smooth,
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=south,},
xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
    ytick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
  enlargelimits=upper] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
  \addplot {gauss(0,0.5)};
  \addplot {gauss(1,0.75)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but the output is:

[image]

How Can I do to have the output:

[image]

?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an `extra description` in order to add the missing descriptions.

The missing x tick label is actually a feature of pgfplots: it attempts to hide potentially obscured tick labels. There is already a feature implemented in the current unstable to reenable those tick labels.

The two "one-tick-distance" bars can be placed by means of custom TikZ instructions. I hope I understood your intention here. I tried to solve it in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.append style={
        mark=none,samples=50,smooth
    },
    axis x line=bottom, 
    axis y line=left, 
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel={\(a \in  \mathbf{Set}(\{\mathbf{mis}_i(X)\}_{i=1}^6 )\)},
    ylabel={\(f_a^{\text{rel}}\)},
    axis y line=middle,
    xlabel={\(x\)},
    ylabel={\(\mathcal{G}_{u,p}(x)\)},
    every axis x label/.style={mark=none,smooth,
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=west,
    },
    every axis y label/.style={
        mark=none,smooth,
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=south,
    },
    xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
    ytick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
    %
    % will become part of pgfplots 1.11 (is already in developer version):
    %hide obscured x ticks=false,
    extra description/.append code={%
        % 
        % pgfplots up to (and including) 1.10 omits tick labels at the
        % intersection of axes. We place it manually: the 0.15cm is
        % the default length of tick lines:
        \node[anchor=north,yshift=-0.15cm/2] at (axis cs:0,0) {$0$};
        %
        % the following uses tikz drawing instructions with pgfplots
        % placement options:
        % (rel axis cs:<x percent>,<y percent>) places relative to the axis size
        % (axis direction cs:<x units>,<y units>) is to be used to *increments* (only)
        % '++' advances the "last point" by the following one:
        \draw[|-|] (rel axis cs:0.8,0.5) -- ++ (axis direction cs:1,0) node[anchor=west] {$=1$};
        %
        \draw[|-|] (rel axis cs:0.8,0.55) ++ (axis direction cs:0.5,0) -- ++ (axis direction cs:0,0.2) node[pos=0.5,anchor=west] {$=0.2$};
        %
        % instead of (rel axis cs:..) ++ (axis direction cs:...)  one
        % could also provide absolute coordinates of the form (axis cs:<x coord>,<y coord>)
    },
    enlargelimits=upper] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
  \addplot {gauss(0,0.5)};
  \addplot {gauss(1,0.75)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I have added inline comments as explanations.

If you want to have a legend which describes the red/blue curves, consider using the `legend entries={...}` key.

Comment: thanks soo much! ;) but ytick=1 is not represented! How Can I do to plot the number 1 in y axis? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, y=1 is outside of the displayed limits. Enlarge them (for example by means of `ymax=1`) and you will have them.